# PHP code is not working inside HTML

Tags: php, mysql, html

As all have commented I have changed my code. Now the thing is when I am running my below php code as separate file its running like charm:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
```

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='username'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Like this: [image]

But when I am trying to include this into html code its not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FusionCharts Column 2D Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
   <?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
```

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='username'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>

</div>
  <div id="chart-container">LOADING....</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
  <script src="js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
  <script src="js/userChart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its giving empty drop box:
[image]

Comment: Uh. are you having a select inside of another select? Which you appear not to be closing either

Comment: you already have an open select in top of the code before printing hi.

Comment: You are generating non-valid HTML.

Comment: `new mysqli...` -> `mysql_query(...)`. Not the same. How are you not getting errors? And stop using `mysql_*` they've been deprecated for such a long time it's not even funny anymore.

Comment: Your code is filled with errors, do learn some basic HTML / php syntax, you can't mix and match mysql / mysqli either.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I am not sure that showing the ip address here is a good idea too

Comment: @RiggsFolly so you're really using my "A kitten dies" expression for `mysql_*`!

Comment: read mysqli vs mysql

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Oh yes all over the place, hope you dont mind a bit of plagurism on my behalf

Comment: @RiggsFolly I feel honoured <3

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Cannot remember if yours had a picture of the dastedly deed being done

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Its strange how few people comment on it, I had expected more

Comment: No no nononono I didn't add an image, I believe the phrase itself is sad enough already.

Comment: Its a bit late to hide the ip address. But you might want to add a password to the root account now as anyone can get into your MYSQL Server Instance now

Comment: Guys sorry for all the mistake I will keep all these things in mind next time posting a question.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary Please, read this first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php If You have to use deprecated PHP, explain this in Your question and add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `select` inside `select` and don't mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*`.Do like below:-

```
<div>
   <select>
        <?php
        require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

        $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        ?>
        <?php
        while ($line = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['username'];?>"> <?php echo $line['username'];?> </option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>

</div>
```

*Note:-*

*file extension must be `.php` not `.html`.*

*Don't use (deprecated + removed) `mysql_*` library. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`*

Comment: Hey anant can you just keep the Note:- part intact. Because that was the mistake and then i ll accept the answer. Thanks I just started learnin php so didn't know abt it.

Comment: The error was using mysqli and naming the file with .html extension.